# How do I selectively extract cells from a Google Spreadsheet and add them to a text document with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I have a spreadsheet on Google Sheets with pricing information. I use the spreadsheet to take prices from a table turn those into commands that I use to change the price in the database software I use.

I usually just copy and paste the values out of the spreadsheet into a text file. Then I take those commands, ssh into my database server and paste the commands to make the changes. I'd like to automate this process a little more as there are hundreds of products in different categories.

My Sheet ends up looking something like

PET FOOD

Cat Food

replace all price with 24.99 for product=catfood

replace all price with 29.99 for product=wetcatfood

NO DATA

Fish Food

replace all price with 5.99 for product=fishflakes

replace all price with 7.85 for product=fishpellets

and ideally the text file output would clean it all up so the title lines and the lines with NO DATA (Which usually means prices remain unchanged) are removed and I'm left with just the commands.

My first attempt at making this process easier was to learn a bit of app script that would hide unwanted rows. It worked, but when I copy + paste the hidden rows pasted too. I don't think this was the best solution anyway.

Is there a way with Google App Scripts I could e-mail a cleaned up .txt file to myself?

Answer (score 0):

```
function extractDataFromSpreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [h,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(h));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs))
}
```

Execution log
11:41:52 AM Notice  Execution started
11:41:53 AM Info    ["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5","COL6","COL7","COL8","COL9","COL10","COL11"]
11:41:53 AM Info    [["A2","B2","C2","D2","E2","F2","G2","H2","I2","J2","K2"],["A3","B3","C3","D3","E3","F3","G3","H3","I3","J3","K3"],["A4","B4","C4","D4","E4","F4","G4","H4","I4","J4","K4"],["A5","B5","C5","D5","E5","F5","G5","H5","I5","J5","K5"],["A6","B6","C6","D6","E6","F6","G6","H6","I6","J6","K6"],["A7","B7","C7","D7","E7","F7","G7","H7","I7","J7","K7"],["A8","B8","C8","D8","E8","F8","G8","H8","I8","J8","K8"],["A9","B9","C9","D9","E9","F9","G9","H9","I9","J9","K9"],["A10","B10","C10","D10","E10","F10","G10","H10","I10","J10","K10"],["A11","B11","C11","D11","E11","F11","G11","H11","I11","J11","K11"],["A12","B12","C12","D12","E12","F12","G12","H12","I12","J12","K12"]]
11:41:54 AM Notice  Execution completed

Spreadsheet:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 | H2 | I2 | J2 | K2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 | H3 | I3 | J3 | K3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 | H4 | I4 | J4 | K4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | I5 | J5 | K5 |
| 6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | I6 | J6 | K6 |
| 7 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | I7 | J7 | K7 |
| 8 | A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | G8 | H8 | I8 | J8 | K8 |
| 9 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | G9 | H9 | I9 | J9 | K9 |
| 10 | A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | G10 | H10 | I10 | J10 | K10 |
| 11 | A11 | B11 | C11 | D11 | E11 | F11 | G11 | H11 | I11 | J11 | K11 |
| 12 | A12 | B12 | C12 | D12 | E12 | F12 | G12 | H12 | I12 | J12 | K12 |